# Where opencart php app code reside on server

Tags: php, opencart

Actully one of my friend has his application on Opencart, he has minimal technical knowledge. And I am not much familiar with PHP and Opencart.
Can anyone tell me where exactly Opencart application code is hosted.
I have root access to SSH, I login and checked in public_html folder but there is nothing.

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: what is the issue in the question, why someone will down-vote seriously. If anything is wrong please let me know as well

Comment: Your question is downvoted because it shows no attempt to resolve, has nothing to do with **php** or **Opencart** and should be asked here https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Oh Sorry, I thought on serverfault.com we ask question related to servers and networks, application specific questions we ask in here. And I thought a person having knowledge of opencart or PHP will be a better person to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` on the server to look for it, or check the HTTP server software configuration.

Using `find`:

```
$ find / -iname opencart
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. `find:/proc/22557: No such file or directory` this error I am getting